# How to remove a field from SQLServer2005 table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE My.Table DROP MyField
```

and got this error:

-MyField is not a constraint.

-Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

There is just one row of data in the table and the field was just added.

**EDIT:**
Just to follow up, the sql was missing COLUMN indeed.
Now I get even more seriously looking errors though:

- The object 'some_object__somenumbers' is dependent on column 'MyField'
- ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN MyField failed because one or more objects access this column.

**EDIT:**

```
ALTER TABLE TableName DROP Constraint ConstraintName
```

worked, after that I was able to use the previous code to remove the column. Credit goes to both of you, thanks.

Comment: You tagged this 'mysql', but the question says SQLServer 2005.  Could you elaborate.

Comment: My mistake, should be mssql, but someone updated it already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brian solved your original problem - for your new problem (The object 'some_object__somenumbers' is dependent on column 'MyField') it means you have a dependancy issue. Something like an index, foreign key reference, default value, etc. To drop the constraint use:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName DROP ConstraintName
```

Also - you'll need to drop all the constraints dependant on that column before it'll let you drop the column itself.

Answer (score 9):

I think you are just missing the COLUMN keyword:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName DROP COLUMN ColumnName
```

You will also need to make sure that any constraint that is depending on ColumnName is dropped first.

You can do this by:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName DROP ConstraintName
```

For each constraint that you have.

If you have indexes based on the column, you will also need to drop those indexes first.

```
DROP INDEX TableName.IndexName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ADD COLUMN SR_NO INTEGER(10)NOT NULL;
```